# Negating a regex test without an "if"

Tags: bash

Ok, I think "bash" is short for "bash my head in."

Got this:

```
! [[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "Supply integer values from the menu only. Nothing added." && return;
```

It' doesn't work. I have to do this:

```
if ! [[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "Supply integer values from the menu only. Nothing added." && return
fi
```

Is there a way to get the first method to work?

UPDATE: Original code was edited. The above edited code works fine. Was a dumb mistake I made while thrashing around trying to figure out how to negate a regex. Closing this out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the order of the operations / operation grouping. You can group operations in bash using curly braces; like this:

```
! [[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo "Supply integer values from the menu only. Nothing added." && return; }
```

note that the `;` is really necessary at the end of the code inside the curly braces.

Comment: Actually, I think I had an `||` in there when I meant `&&`.

Comment: that would really explain the difference in behavious yes. Now I suppose both your code samples do the same.
In any case my answer still stands if you wanted to use the `||` operator; since bash operations order isn't that simple to impose otherwise

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd one is:

```
if ! [[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "Supply integer values from the menu only. Nothing added." && return
fi
```

So the echo... executed when the regex doesn't match.
But in the first example, you use OR (|| in bash):

```
! [[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || echo "Supply integer values from the menu only. Nothing added." && return;
```

so the echo executed when the `! [[ ... ]]` expression fails, that is the opposite what you wrote with the if. The same would be:

```
! [[ $var =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "Supply integer values from the menu only. Nothing added." && return;
```

Comment: Yeah, I screwed up. I was trying different things to get the regex to negate and one fo them was changing the `&&` to `||`. I couldn't figure out where the hell to put the exclamation point.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what "doesn't work" means, but your two statements aren't equivalent.

```
1195$ ! false || echo hello
1196$ ! true || echo hello
hello

1197$ if ! false; then echo hello ; fi
hello
1198$ if ! true; then echo hello ; fi
```

The roles of true and false are reversed between the two different usages.